# A Group $G$ with $G \cong G \times G \times G$ and $G \not \cong G \times G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when is A isomorphic to A^3?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3)

Does there exist a group $G$ such that $G \cong G \times G \times G$ and $G \not \cong G \times G$?  If such groups exist, can $G$ be countable?

Tangentially, it is known that there is no such linear order (replacing direct product with concatenation) and that there are such Boolean algebras (replacing direct product with direct sum).

Comment: Duplicate question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3. The answer is yes. 

Comment: Although it has been asked before, let me add, Asher, that it is a great question! It's just that it seems best to keep the answers and discussion all together in one place.

Comment: Thanks!  And agreed.  Is there any reason not to delete my question?

Comment: A mild argument for *not* deleting this question: when I tried to find a question about this theme earlier this week using mathoverflow, I never found the original question because there the notation is A, not G. 