# Groups with $G^n \cong G$ for some integer $n$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Which integers $n>2$ have the following property?

There is a group $G$ such that

- $G^n \cong G$; and
- for all integers $k$ with $1<k<n$ we have $G^k\not \cong G$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with abelian groups for any $n$; see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10194/75) to a very similar question.