# A kind of cancellation ; exchange problem for groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

For which $(m,n,k,l) \in (\mathbb N\cup \{0\})^4$ , with $m\le n ; k\le l$ , does there exist a group $G$ with a finite subnormal series with torsion-free Abelian quotients such that $G \times \mathbb Z^n \cong G \times \mathbb Z^l$ but $G \times \mathbb Z^m \ncong G \times \mathbb Z^k$ ?

[$A$ is isomorphic to $A \oplus \mathbb{Z}^2$, but not to $A \oplus \mathbb{Z}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218113/a-is-isomorphic-to-a-oplus-mathbbz2-but-not-to-a-oplus-mathbbz)  shows $(0,0,1,2)$ is such a pair .

NOTE : Also previously asked on Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340835/a-kind-of-cancellation-exchange-problem-for-groups

Comment: The construction in my answer to the linked question generalizes straightforwardly to give, for any $d$,  a torsion free abelian group with $G\oplus\mathbb{Z}^r\cong G\oplus\mathbb{Z}^s$ if and only if $d$ divides $r-s$, so a sufficient condition is that $n-l$ does not divide $m-k$. For abelian groups, Walker's Cancellation Theorem shows that this is also a necessary condition. Is there any particular reason for the class of groups you're interested in?

Comment: @JeremyRickard : Well , for a field $k$ , and a group $G$ with a finite subnormal series with torsion-free Abelian quotients , Kaplansky's unit conjecture holds for $k[G]$ ; so if $G,H$ are two such groups then $k[G] \cong k[H]$ would imply $G \cong H$ if $k$ is finite ... I was trying to get some cancellation; exchange properties for Laurent polynomial rings from these observations ... your example is even better by the way ( though I haven't worked out it fully yet)  .. because $G$ is abelian and then $k[G]$ is commutative ring ...