# Is "square" functor monomorphic on objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, products

I am trying to find whether the polynomial (monomial) functor $P : X \rightarrow X\times X $, i.e. $P(X) = X^2$, is monomorphic on objects, in other words, that if there exists an isomorphism $A\times A \overset {i} {\hookrightarrow} B \times B$, then there is also an isomorphism $A \overset {j} {\hookrightarrow} B$.

I understand that it is important to use the fact that those are squares, i.e. products of isomorphic objects, else it doesn't hold (indeed, $A \times A = (A\times A)\times 1$, etc.).

However I have trouble to figure out the path of the proof. I'm not even sure the property holds outside of the category $Sets$.

Comment: That's not what 'faithful' means in my book. What you wrote looks closer to (but is not the same as) the notion of conservative functor: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor

Comment: Yes, thank you. Let me fix it.
Let's say "mono on objects" for now.

Comment: Of course it holds in the category of sets.

Comment: @HeinrichD Yes, and in Sets this property requires the axiom of choice (Tarski theorem) to hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218113/a-is-isomorphic-to-a-oplus-mathbbz2-but-not-to-a-oplus-mathbbz/227443#227443) $A$ that is isomorphic to $A \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ but not isomorphic to $A \times \mathbb Z$.

Taking $B = \mathbb A \times \mathbb Z$ produces a counterexample in the category of abelian groups.

Comment: see also the Boolean algebra counterexample https://mathoverflow.net/a/227525/18060

Comment: thank you so much!!
This counter-example with groups is perfect.

Comment: Just a historical comment: Whether there are non-isomorphic abelian groups with $A\times A\cong B\times B$ was Kaplansky’s second “test problem” from 1954, and the first example was published by Jonsson in 1957, long before anybody looked for examples of abelian groups with $A\times\mathbb{Z}\not\cong A\cong A\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.