# A question about retracts of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory

A group $H$ is called a retract of a group $G$ if there exist homomorphisms $f:H\longrightarrow G$ and $g:G\longrightarrow H$ such that $g\circ f=id_H$.  By a trivial retract of $G$, I just mean the trivial group and $G$ itslef.

My question is that:

Is there a group admitting non-trivial retracts, and which is a retract of all its non-trivial retracts"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are lots of groups without nontrivial retracts.

Comment: So certainly the question should be "Is there a group admitting non-trivial retracts, and which is a retract of all its non-trivial retract"?

Comment: Yes. I mean that the group $G$ must  contains non-trivial retracts.

Comment: My apology for this comment in the answer part. I can not give a comment since I am under 50 reputation. Are there two non isomorphic groups which are retract of each others?

Comment: This blog post discusses some related results: https://berstein2015.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/a-group-with-a-quotient-isomorphic-to-the-direct-square/ .

Comment: @AliTaghavi you'd be above 50 if you were not systematically spending your reputation for bounties. (Anyway, this is somewhat a bug of the system: it's absurd you can't comment because of bounties.)

Comment: @AliTaghavi yes. Let $A,B$ be infinite sets of the same cardinal with union $D$. For $C_k$ cyclic group of order $k$, let $C_2$ act nontrivially on $C_3$. Then $(C_3\rtimes C_2)^D=(C_3^D\rtimes C_2^D)=C_3^B\rtimes (C_3^A\rtimes C_2^D)$ and $C_3^A\rtimes C_2^D=(C_3^A\rtimes C_2^A)\times C_2^B$, so $(C_3\rtimes C_2)^D$ and $(C_3\rtimes C_2)^D\times C_2^D$ are isomorphic to retracts of each other. But the second one has nontrivial center unlike the first one, so they're not isomorphic.

Comment: @AliTaghavi According to answers to [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3), there is an Abelian group $A$ such that $A\cong A^3$ but $A\not\cong A^2.$ Clearly $A$ is a retract of $A^2$ while $A^2$ is an retract of $A^3\cong A$. Therefore, $A$ and $A^2$ are non-isomorphic groups which are retracts of each other.

Comment: @YCor  l honestly thank you very much for your two previous comments:  Your interesting example and your comment on my reputation.

Comment: @M.Ramana  thank you very much for the link and your interesting counter example.

Comment: @YCor why not make that an answer?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow my example addressed Ali Taghavi's question in a comment, but not the OP. For instance, $C_2$ is a nontrivial retract of the group $G$ given in my comment, but $G$ is not isomorphic to any retract of $C_2$.