# About direct products of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that $G\simeq G\times G\times G$ (here $\simeq$ is an isomorphism of groups). Is it true that in this case $G\simeq G\times G$? Of course, this question is slightly artifitial. But it is interesting whether someone knows the answer.

Comment: The answer is "no", see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3